# How to place a photo in the top left of header of my website

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6

This is my [site](http://www.indiacustomercare.com). 
I want to place a customer care executive's photo in the top left of the website header which is empty now. 
How can I do it?
I'm not able to figure out why the graphic placed in #header isn't placed on the top-left that is there is some space on the left side.

I'd like to add the photo as separate one. If I can't then I can merge the photo along with the existing graphic header(containing company logos..).

Which will be best option?

Comment: The left side has a set of company logos. Do you want this photo on top of the company logos? Or do you mean the right side of the header?

Comment: There is some space on the left side of the company logos. I want to place the executive's photo here. I can't understand why space is there before the company logo's. In css file I don't find any left margin for #header div in which company logo is placed.

Comment: This site has a white gap on top(from #header-region). Gradients are out of place(both FF/Chrome/IE8) . I do not see where you can get any image on that left end. How about the right end? I also do not know what an executive's photo is. do you have dimensions of this executive's photo?

Comment: I've a woman executive's photo and we can resize it to be same height that of company logo image. What do you mean by gradients out of place? I think I'll  have to merge both executive photo placing it in the left side of the company logo.

Comment: Do you not see the gradients/shadows not aligning? http://bit.ly/fgaaVL

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm thinking how to correct it. There is mismatch since background gradient mismatches with the company logo gradient filled in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the company logos image is a background, so it is not going to be affected by anything you put inside the div#header. It really doesn't need to be a background, but it's not hurting anything that way. I would remove the gradient in Photoshop and save it as a PNG with a transparent background. That will fix the issue with lining up the gradients.

As for inserting the image you can do this -

HTML -

```
<div id="header"><img src="path/to/executive/image.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS -

```
#header{background:url(path/to/logos/image.png) no-repeat XXXpx 0px;}
```

You will need to replace XXXpx with a size at least the same width or larger than the image you want to display so that the logos do not show up beneath that image.

Comment: To complete Brent Friar answer, you should edit your page.tpl.php inside your theme module